# adding element to parent from directive

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In order to disable the auto complete of chrome in forms, i want to create angular directive which add dummy input element
my code is
     `angular.module("noc.components").directive('customInput', function           ($compile) {
       "use strict";

```
return {
    restrict:'E',
    template:'<input>',
    replace:true,
    link: function(scope, elem) {
        //scope.type = attrs.type || 'email';
        var el = angular.element('<input name={{type}} style="display: none">');
        //var type = elem[0].name;
        $compile(el)(scope);
        elem.parent().append(el);
    }
};
```

});`

and the html is

```
<div class="form-group">
                                <label for="setupWizardUserStepEmail">Email Address</label>
                                <custom-input class="form-control"
                                       id="setupWizardUserStepEmail"
                                       ng-model="setupRequest.userRequest.email"
                                       name="email"
                                       ng-required="true"
                                       noc-validation="email"
                                       autocomplete="off"
                                        autofocus="true">
                            </div>
```

however the injected html isnt in the parent - i want it to be above the directive
how can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my own problem in the end:

I changed it to `elem.parent().prepend(el);`